# GitStack fail to create new repository

Tags: git, version-control, repository, gitstack

I have installed GitStack 2.3.9 with default settings.

I need to create a new repository with name `01.Test` using the UI page'Repositories' where in the end of the of page there is 'Create repository' with a textbox. The UI is like [this](https://gitstack.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/repository_list.png).

But I get the below error message which is displayed in the beginning of the page when I press the 'Create' button.

> Please enter an alphanumeric name without spaces

If I try to create a new repository without dot with name `01Test` it succeeded.

**How can I create repository with dot in the name?**

Comment: Can you explain how you create the repository? In my case, I create the repositories by creating a folder, then going in that folder and running `git init` and then adding and committing whatever things you have in your folder. Doing it this way I was able to create a git in a folder that contained a dot `abc.def`

Comment: For both repo creations I use the GitStack UI page 'Repositories' in the end of the of page there is 'Create repository' with a textbox. The UI is like [this](https://gitstack.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/repository_list.png). The error message is displayed in the beginning of the page when I press the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, git repo name `01.Test` with dot/peroid is **invalid** in GitStack.

As the message shows, only **alphanumeric name** is available for GitStack.

So only repo names contain `a`-`z` or `0`-`9` are valid.